# Changing 'stylesheets' folder's name on Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

### The big deal

I want to change the `stylesheets` folder's name to `css`.

### Going deeper

Actually, I already changed it – I need to (re)educate Rails about that.

When I use `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'all.min' %>`, I want to search within `assets/css/` instead of `assets/stylesheets/` – the requested file itself is searched on `/stylesheets/all.min.css` by `application.html.erb` layout.

### My bets

I tried nothing because I don't even know where's the beginning.

### Technical details

- Rails 4.1.1
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Windows 8.1

Comment: I think Rails need to (re)educate you. Why would you want to go against the grain? Convention over configuration, and all that.

Comment: I love these pragmatic answers – I really learn with it! Anyhow, I forgot about "convention over configuration" and you're right – I need to be reeducated. I will keep the specificed convention by Rails. I think it's conceptually better. Thank you! (By the way, the question wasn't answered itself.)

Comment: No problem. Sticking to conventions will save you a lot of headaches down the road.

Comment: Any reasons why you're trying to do this? Don't worry, I support it - just curious as to your reasons?

Comment: @RichPeck I have my own application naming patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the way to do it is.

```
# in application.rb
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/css"
```

And restart your server. However, as stated in a comment on the question, it is really advisable to stick to Rails's conventions unless you really need to do otherwise. It will save you a lot of trouble.